# Why Angular doesn't use Angular's router module in their application angular.io?

Tags: angular

I am searching solution for fragment routing in Angular. But `@angular/router` module doesn't support it, I mean it's not working what is there for fragments. However, there is a lot of opened issue for that on github. From my observations, [angular.io](https://angular.io/docs) documentation page has very nice, working fragment routing. I was curious about that and I started digging into [their repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/). I had hope, that they have solution for fragment routing in `@angular/router`. But no luck. I saw that they aren't use their own `@angular/router` module.

The question is, why they aren't using own router module, because of fragment routing doesn't work or what?